# Вылетает Android Studio при запуске

Tags: android, android-studio

Скачал Android Studio. Установил, все по видео из ютуба, по видео с офф сайта, все делал так как показано. Запускаю, создаю проект, дальше билдинг проекта, чето грузит, собирает, открыты два окна мейнАктивити.кт и мейнАктивити.xml. Вверху написано слово анализинг и все, на этом вылет из программы. Сначала думал проблема с оперативкой, нехватает, на деле 60% занято. переустановил винду, просто хотелось давно, и еще потому что, думал, что поможет, так как до этого устанавливал intellij idea и JDK тоже, а андроид студио устанавливает JDK автоматически, ну думал удалю, все получится, не получилось, не могу найти ответа на свой вопрос, перезапускал, пересоздавал проект, никак не могу понять, в чем проблема. помогите! я чайник, поэтому заумных текстов не пойму, пишите, пожалуйста, проще. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: хотя бы скрин ошибки добавь. Как по-твоему мы поймем в чем проблема ?

Comment: Какая операционная система у тебя ? , если windows 10 обнови до последней версий , и скачай 
1) (java)                                    : https://java.com/ru/download/
2) (directx )                               : https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=35
3) (Пакет Microsoft Visual C++) : https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-160
4) (Microsoft Net Framework)    : https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=17851